# HAProxy HTTP Codes

Tags: haproxy, http-status-code

I was wondering if is there any way to track different HTTP codes that HAProxy send to clients.

For example, have a log with just a list of different status codes:

```
200
200
302
404
499
500
```

Having that, I can graph it with rrdtool or something else.

Comment: Do you want only the status code?

Comment: No, not only but at least the status code

Comment: The HTTP log format contains the status code (field 7).

Comment: Yeah, but that's in the backend. I need to track it directly on haproxy server (different machines)

Comment: haproxy itself can log: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#8.2.3

Answer (score 1):

HAProxy provides the status code in the httplog format:

> - "status_code" is the HTTP status code returned to the client. This status
>     is generally set by the server, but it might also be set by haproxy when
>     the server cannot be reached or when its response is blocked by haproxy.

You just need to activate it with `option httplog`

http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.4.html#8.2.3